# Beginner Node/React/MySQL -> querying the db and displaying the result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React app that is connected to the backend via Express, where I query an SQL database to retrieve data. Final goal is to display that data via React.

> Problem

I can't `map` through the list of elements returned by the SQL query. I'm too much of a beginner to tell why, but my guess is that it's because the returned data from the SQL query is an `object`, and I need an `array` to map it. So it **returns an error**: `TypeError: this.state.allwatches.filter is not a function`.

> Server.js *(seems to be working)*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;  
var mysql      = require('mysql');  

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'Watches'
});

app.get('/getWatchesList', (req, res) => {
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * from WatchesList', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));
        } else {
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        }
    });
    connection.end();
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

> WatchesList.js *(**seems to cause problems**)*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Components
import Watche from './WatchesList_Components/Watche.js'

class WatchesList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = 
    {
      allwatches : ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/getWatchesList')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(allwatches_ => this.setState({allwatches: allwatches_}, () => console.log("successfully fetched allwatches", allwatches_)))
  }

  render() {
    let filteredWatches = this.state.allwatches.filter((watche) => {
        return watche.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) > -1;
    });
    return (
        <div>
        { 
            filteredWatches.map(
                (product) => {
                return <Watche name={product.name} price={product.price} image={product.image} />
            })
        } 
        </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default WatchesList;
```

Comment: You clearly state in your code that `allwatches` is just an empty string. Maybe that's a mistake or it needs to be populated properly? You may also be failing to wait for that async call to run, so `componentDidMount` may need to return a promise, or wait for the result.

Comment: @tadman I don't understand. I set allwatches to nothing initially, but then componentDidMount should update its state and insert the data in it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I had to replace in server.js `res.json(rows);` instead of `res.send(JSON.stringify(rows));`, and in my component I had to add an empty array in my state, so I went from `allwatches : ''` to `allwatches : []`
`

Comment: You should be careful when initializing things to nonsense values like that. A lot of JavaScript code is asynchronous meaning the order of operations is not always obvious. Whenever possible leave things uninitialized rather than populated with dummy values like an empty string. I think this "fix" makes that code operate on your empty array without error until it's properly populated, but that might not be your intent.